# VBA Class Creation

Tags: vba

I am going to be a bit vague here, because I am using a proprietary object library which doesn't see much action here on SO.  That said, I will also say that I don't have a great intuition when it comes to creating classes in VBA.  Here is my question.

I have an object.  This object contains a group of objects.  This group of objects can be produced and consumed in real time.  Because of how intense this process is, I should not just add all items and let it sit.  I also should not add all and remove all, but that is just terrible and lazy coding, not to mention the fact that it's probably the worst performance wise.

My thought is I should be able to create a class that produces and consumes elements for me, in a way.  I've tested this, and it is most certainly the best cost for performance.

Here is an example:
My main "page" contains a variable:

```
    Public eGroup As tagGroup

    Option Explicit
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Set up tag group for use
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Private Sub theTags()
        If eGroup Is Nothing Then
            Set eGroup = Application.CreateTagGroup("frmItemControl", 250)
            With eGroup
                .RemoveAll
                .Add "State"
                .Add "Status"
            End With
        End If
        eGroup.active = True
    End Sub
```

As mentioned, subsequent routine performance is best found by producing and consuming elements of the object (assuming the following is anywhere other than the above variable\code):

```
Public Sub enable(location As String, tagName As String)
    Dim tag As String
    Dim eTag As tag
    ' Set PLC order query handshake bit
    tag = "Machine\VB_HS_" & tagName
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Add tag
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item(tag)
    eTag.Value = True
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Remove tag
    Set eTag = Nothing
End Sub
```

So in a nutshell, my main page has an object, to which I need to add an element to the object, be able to read\write to the elements value, and remove the object, hopefully in a single line of code.

I am reaching out for all of your advice.  Am I on the right track?  Can I do what I want with the creation of a class?  If so, can you provide an example of what I want to do, or how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Another example.  If I simply just want to change a value within the eGroup array of elements, the current proposed way is to do this *each and every time I want to read\write from an element of the array*:

```
tag = "Machine\BinRejectCount"
ThisDisplay.eGroup.Add tag
Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item(tag)
eTag.Value = 0
ThisDisplay.eGroup.Remove tag
```

Update 2:

Based on Tim William's suggestion, my next itteration of this code would be wrapped in a module as follows:

```
Dim eTag As tag

Public Sub w(tagName As String, tagValue As Variant)
    tag = tagName 
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Add tag
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item(tag)
    eTag.Value = tagValue
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Remove tag
    Set eTag = Nothing
End Sub


Public Function r(tagName As String) As Variant
    tag = tagName
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Add tag
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.item(tag)
    r = eTag.Value
    ThisDisplay.eGroup.Remove tag
    Set eTag = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It's difficult to see why you'd want to do that all in a single line of code?  Does adding and then immediately removing the element have some persisting effect?

Comment: @TimWilliams Well for several reasons, but the main reason is code performance.  Other reasons include basic readability, maintainability, and just plain less code. 
 This particular piece of software, has probably over 30K lines of code and it can be significantly reduced if I figure out a way to do this.  At the moment, it's done the lazy way and the performance is severely impacted by it, especially so when reaching across multiple instances of the application to get the values.

Comment: Is `tagGroup` your own class, or from the library you're working with? It's not clear where the boundary is here.  It seems like your `enable` sub already packages those specific steps effectively: so whether that needs to be in a class or not is to some extent a matter of preference.

Comment: @TimWilliams tagGroup is a part of the library.  `theTags` is where the initial setup occurs.  But anywhere and everywhere I want to use an element in the code, I'd like to `.Add` it, either read or write to `.Value`, then `.Remove`.  That is a lot of unnecessary code if it can be helped.  Just a guess, but this is probably 30% of the code if done this way.  I'll post another example.

Comment: If you warp that last example up as a Sub with two parameters (tag and value) then all calls to perform those actions would be one line of code.

Comment: I'll have to evaluate that.  I feel that because eTag is an instantiated input and output value, it would be better to wrap it in a class.  But like I said, I'm not all that intuitive regarding appropriate class building and use.

Comment: @TimWilliams do you feel what I've posted would be best here?

Comment: I would avoid that global eTag unless it needs to be shared, but that just going on what you've posted.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yep, this method works.  I was concerned about using a variant data type, but it seems to be okay.  I'll test it more extensively when I get back to work in the morning.  Thanks for your input!  Post an answer!